# how to add text view and radio buttons in the scroll view?

Tags: android

I have to add one text view and two radio buttons in the scroll view so after reading all text user can scroll to last and select one of radio button.
but I am unable to add both the components in scroll view, once i added to text view in the scroll view , when I am trying to add Radio group , it is not being added.

So please help me achieve the same.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ScrollView` can host only one direct child you better add a parent layout common to both i.e. add a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` to your `TextView` and `RadioGroup`

Do something like this..

```
<ScrollView
 .......
 .......>

  <LinearLayout 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  ......
  ......>
   <TextView
    ......
    ....../>
   <RadioGroup
    ....
    ..../>
  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textview" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/rb1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rb2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rb3" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @Ghost-Please correct your answer from `CheckBox` to `RadioGroup` before somebody could downvote.

Comment: @VivekKalkur: Thanks! Hadn't seen that.

Comment: @VivekKalkur: :) +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:
ScrollView 
LinearLayout with width fill-parent and height as fill_parent and orientation as "vertical"
TextView 
RadiaoGroup 
/LinearLayout
/ScrollView